# Not working with json but working with urlencoding in Postman

Tags: angularjs, playframework, csrf

I am stuck, I spent almost whole day to solve this problem.
I am trying to integrate csrf security to our website that is written with play framework 2.5.9 and angularjs 1.x. I added csrf things and I tried to test via postman.
While it works as content-type is set to x-www-form-urlencoded however not working when it is set to application/json. It gives me

```
Content-Length →0
Date →Tue, 14 Mar 2017 13:22:13 GMT
error →No CSRF token found for application/json body
```

and my json is

```
{
    "username": "admin", 
    "email": "admin", 
    "password": "123456", 
    "consumer": "consumer",
    "csrfToken": "c29625a2c1c26bfbd4e74f6f6499d21f9a21aed-1489470934941-ae012aab7984ed13bfc697ea"
}
```

what's wrong with it? Do I miss something?
Any help, appreciated.

**EDIT:**
By the way,
when I disable csrf check in application.conf by adding following lines

```
X-Requested-With = "*"
Csrf-Token = "nocheck"
```

post method works for application/json content-type.

Comment: Have you tried to do this? https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SecurityHeaders you gotta enable the filters on play in order to use them

Comment: Actually this link is really what you need. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCsrf#Adding-a-CSRF-token-to-the-session and also check on your request if you REALLY have the token on the header of the request

Comment: I enabled csrf and cors filters as mentioned @pedroct92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play [default CSRF protection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf) filter check the

1. Query string
2. Header
3. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type
4. `multipart/form-data` content type

You can check the source:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/csrf/CSRFActions.scala#L425

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/csrf/CSRFActions.scala#L66

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/csrf/CSRFActions.scala#L90

So what you can do:

1. Add `csrfToken` to the query string `...?csrfToken=...`(not recommended)
2. Add `crfToken` to the headers
3. Disable it
4. Write your own CSRF filter

Comment: btw, "post method works for application/json content-type." looks strange, I suppose it rewrite content type, because according to the source it must not work: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/csrf/CSRFActions.scala#L82

Comment: Yes, it does. I've also used on the other methods POST/PUT/DELETE they work as long I place on my request the token that I've placed somewhere on the page `beforeSend: xhr.setRequestHeader 'Csrf-Token', $('input[name=\'csrfToken\']').val()`

Comment: Answer is not fully true. Play's CSRF Protection works with AJAX and arbitrary requests via Crsf-Token Header. 
_To allow simple protection for non browser requests, Play only checks requests with cookies in the header. If you are making requests with AJAX, you can place the CSRF token in the HTML page, and then add it to the request using the Csrf-Token header._
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf#Plays-CSRF-protection

Comment: @AlexanderB yes, I did not recognize the header check, will update the answer